# Screen zoomed in

Tags: kubuntu, screen

I was working in Mathematica and I was pushing shift+Enter many times. Suddenly, something happened to my screen. It is zoomed in. I don't see whole desktop and when I move mouse my screen is moving. I went to CompizConfig and Enhanced Zoom Desktop was disabled.

System: Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you try activating *Enhanced Zoom Desktop*  and zoom out?

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (try this first):
Try `sudo service lightdm stop` in you terminal.
Then if your desktop disappears, `sudo service lightdm start`
If it doesn't work, then use option 2.

Option 2:
Try `pkill x` in your terminal.
If you get something like: `no such process: x` and you have tried option one, I can't help you.
If your desktop does disappear, run `startx`

Here's how it works (for both):

1. Terminate the X server
2. Restart X server

There are alternatives, but this one always works for me.